# How can we alter Id of an existing event in FullCalendar 5.3.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

Can I change Id of an event that is already rendered in FullCalendar 5.3.2?
The condition which I am facing I want to move the event from one date to another which updates the eventId at the backend I want to update it on Calendar also.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `I want to move the event from one date to another which updates the eventId at the backend` ... that sounds like a bad design flaw in your database, to be honest. The ID should be unique and immutable. Changing a property of an object should not alter its ID. Otherwise other code, data etc which maintains a reference to that event will break. In general, applications and databases never do what you're describing because it causes too many problems. So whilst it may be possible to do what you want in fullCalendar, my advice is "don't do that, fix your database instead."

Comment: @ADyson We have a kind of requirement where every dragged and dropped event will be treated as a new event. So one solution could be I just delete the exiting event and create a new one with a new id one on drag and drop.

Comment: `We have a kind of requirement where every dragged and dropped event will be treated as a new event` ...that's a very strange requirement. It's just moving the event. I'm not sure that requirement is really essential - what problem does it solve for you, to need the requirement like that? I suggest questioning the logic of this. But it sounds like what would be happening is basically the same as deleting and re-creating, so yes you could do that. But I think the whole concept, including the requirement, sounds misguided.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a very bad thing to do, but i think `event.setProp` is what you want.

in your case it would be something like

```
event.setProp( 'id', 'newId');
```

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Event-setProp